# .htaccess rewrite rule - custom structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible to create a .htaccess rule which will take the middle of a URL structure, but resume the normal REQUEST_URL (Sorry for my terrible explanation)

Take this URL for example
/boats/283/manage/water

Now let's say I'm keeping the hierarchy standardisation as per the URL structure, minus the ID (ID in this case is 287) - so the actual script location is /boats/manage/water(.php)

But obviously I don't have to have a manual rule for each page, as that will get tedious.

eg (What I want to avoid per page).

```
RewriteRule ^boats/(\d+)/manage/water$ ./boats/manage/water.php?id=$1  
RewriteRule ^boats/(\d+)/manage/bacon$ ./boats/manage/bacon.php?id=$1
```

I have no doubt I could find something relevant in Google, but I just can't quite come up with the proper keywords..

Any help/push in the right direction is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
# group out the first path, the ID, then the rest
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(\d+)/(.*)$
# pre-check that the destination php file actually exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/%3.php -f
# rewrite
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%3.php?id=%2 [L]
```

Comment: I see what you've done here, but I don't think it will work in my case. (Please note that I am trying to learn regex, not just expecting a straight-forward answer :-)) - Am I correct in saying that if the PHP script is not on the first path's literal directory, the pre-check will fail - thus causing the rewrite not to work?

Comment: @Spinkzeit The path that the php file is checked against is `/%1/%3.php` where **%1** is the first path node before the ID, and **%3** is everything *after* the ID. So given, `/blah/123/foo/bar`, the precheck is made for `/blah/foo/bar.php`

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. Another question, regarding
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(\d+)/(.*)$
Why is it not
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} ^/([^/]+)/(\d+)/(.*)$

Comment: Disregard that, I worked it out.
If my ID (\d+) is not a digit, is it as easy as just changing it to (\s+) for a string ID?

Comment: @Spinkzeit No, `\s` would match the `/` character, you should just replace `(\d+)` with `([^/]+)`

Comment: Thank you :) I'm going to presume ([^/]+) means accept any character, essentially. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Spinkzeit It's any character that is not (`^`) the `/` character. If the id's are letters or numbers, you can also use `([A-Za-z0-9]+)`